# Path.GetFullPath given bad path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am choosing to upload a file named about.png which is in location "C:\images\about.png"
But when I step through the code after getting a file not found error I see it is always setting the path to this
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\about.png"

I did upload this to my web server and got the same result so it is not a local issue.
The strange thing is Visual Studio is installed on the E drive not the C drive which adds even more confusion. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code.

```
request.FilePath = Path.GetFullPath(filefield.FileName);
```

**Added Note: The file can come from anywhere as the user would be choosing a profile picture. I forgot to mention this is a upload procedure**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uploaded file contents are part of HTTP request - the ASP.NET File Upload control does not save the file on the disk. You have to do that manually by using [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) method.

The FileName property provides only the file name because path information will be from client machine and it does not have any relevance on the server machine. So if you try 
`Path.GetFullPath` to get the full path on the file name - it being only relative path, will give path w.r.t. current directory - in your case, it turns out to be the path development web server (that comes with Visual Studio).

Typically, you should use `SaveAs` method to store the upload file at the designated location on the web server - the file name used while saving should be a generated one (say guid or some other id) and store the actual file name in the database along with the generated file name. This is because the upload file name may not be valid on the server machine (consider someone uploads file from MAC or Linux machine). Yet another way is to save the file on disk at temp location and then push the contents into the database itself.

Comment: So do i need to save the file to the webserver then upload it to Amazon s3 then delete the file? (That is my main goal)

Comment: @GregGoodwin, that's correct - save the file at the temp location on the web server and then upload it to Amazon store.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetFullPath(...)` returns the path of the provided file name relative to your current directory.

Usually your current directory is where the application is running from, so if you're running from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\` then that output is right.

What you may have to do is extract the filename from the given `filefield` using `Path.GetFileName`, then create an absolute path to where you want to save it to using `Path.GetFullPath`.

The documentation of [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) explains this fairly cleanly:

```
string fileName = "myfile.ext";
string path1 = @"mydir";
string path2 = @"\mydir";
string fullPath;

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path1);
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path1, fullPath);

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, fullPath);

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path2);
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path2, fullPath);

// Output is based on your current directory, except
// in the last case, where it is based on the root drive
// GetFullPath('mydir') returns 'C:\temp\Demo\mydir'
// GetFullPath('myfile.ext') returns 'C:\temp\Demo\myfile.ext'
// GetFullPath('\mydir') returns 'C:\mydir'
```

Comment: :No explanation of temp, Demo direcotires.

Comment: @Hoque: In this case it's to be inferred that the application's current directory is in `C:\temp\Demo\`

Comment: :The above example demonstrates the GetFullPath method on a Windows-based desktop platform.(the link mentioned it)